# Add GraphiteReporter to Kafka Connect cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm having trouble getting Kafka Connect to send metrics: `kafka.consumer:*` and `kafka.connect:*` to Graphite. List found here: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_monitoring

So far I built and added this JAR in /usr/share/java/kafka-graphite-clients-0.10.2.jar

https://github.com/apakulov/kafka-graphite

and updated the worker config by posting this to the connect rest api:

```
{ 
    "metric.reporters": "org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.GraphiteReporter",
    "kafka.graphite.metrics.reporter.enabled": true,
    "kafka.graphite.metrics.host": "my.graphite.host",
    "kafka.graphite.metrics.prefix": "my.prefix",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "10",
    "topics": "topic1,topic2",
    "s3.region": "us-east-1",
    "s3.bucket.name": "my-bucket",
    "s3.part.size": "5242880",
    "s3.compression.type": "gzip",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "900000",
    "flush.size": "1000000",
    "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.bytearray.ByteArrayFormat",
    "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
    "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
    "name": "s3-sink"
}
```

I can't seem to get the GraphiteReporter picked up and I'm not sure why. Is this not the correct way of getting those metrics into Graphite?

Comment: You'll have to edit the connect distributed properties, and restart the Connect server. You can't add reporters per connector

Comment: Ok I will try that. To summarize, in a k8s setup I would need to mount the `metric.reporters` and `kafka.graphite.*` properties into the `connect-distributed.properties` file in `/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties`. Besides that can you confirm if the `GraphiteReporter` I'm referencing does indeed work to report jmx domains: `kafka.connect:*` and `kafka.consumer:*`

Comment: I've not used it... Based on the README, it was written before connect really had JMX metrics, though, but the consumer ones should work

Comment: Ah well it’s worth a try but I’d really like to get those kafka.connect metrics as well. Have you ever used jmx2graphite?

Comment: I haven't, but I think any JMX exporter you use should be able to get what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

If somebody ever needs this, we are running the same reporter implementation successfully by placing it under

`/usr/share/java/kafka/`